# SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier on table that exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a column to an existing database column using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE REVISION ADD COLUMN IS_BLACK NUMBER(1);
```

I get the following back:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - ALTER TABLE REVISION ADD
> COLUMN IS_BLACK NUMBER(1)
>
> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00904: :
> invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Revision is a table, I can run describe on it and it outputs.  What is the invalid identifier?  I'm confused and can't find answers online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `COLUMN`; it's being seen as a column name, and is an invalid name because it's a reserved word.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE revision (ID NUMBER); 

Table REVISION created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE REVISION ADD IS_BLACK NUMBER(1);

Table REVISION altered.
```

You can see the correct syntax [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2103924).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify `column` in the statement. It should be

```
ALTER TABLE REVISION ADD IS_BLACK NUMBER(1);
```